# Understanding Linux Environment backward-slash and asterisk uses

Tags: shell-script, zip

I have two related questions in a Linux environment.

I am confused when to use backward-slash `\` and combining with asterisk "*".
When I try to run Unzip *.zip the command fails until I escape it. Why is it so?

```
developer@tz:~/f$ bash -version
GNU bash, version 4.3.48(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later 
developer@tz:~/f$ unzip *.zip
Archive:  abstract.zip
caution: filename not matched:  date-function.zip
developer@tz:~/f$ unzip \*.zip
Archive:  abstract.zip
  inflating: abstract.xsl            

Archive:  date-function.zip
warning [date-function.zip]:  zipfile is empty

1 archive was successfully processed.
1 archive had warnings but no fatal errors.
developer@tz:~/f$ ls *.zip
abstract.zip  date-function.zip
developer@tz:~/f$ ls \*.zip
ls: cannot access '*.zip': No such file or directory
```

On the similar issue regarding one-liner functions.

Suppose I have zip files: foo.zip and bar.zip in same directory and I need to extract both; when I do:

```
ls *.zip | xargs -IZIP  basename -s .zip ZIP
```

the above commands will list: foo and bar on konsole, but when I run:

```
ls *.zip | xargs -IZIP unzip ZIP -d $( basename -s .zip ZIP )
```

it fails to run because when I pass the results of base, it does NOT get a value, hence it fails.

1. When do I use "\" or "*" or combine both when invoking konsole commands?
2. How can I extract the zip file to a directory with its own name?

Comment: Notes: 1) It isn't a good idea to parse the output of `ls`. 2) On my system, `unzip(1)` contains a great deal of information under the "Examples" heading.  Perhaps the same is true of yours?

Answer (score 4):

The usage of `unzip` in particular may lead to some confusion.  It can be called as

```
$ unzip x.zip file-1 file-2 file-3
```

where `file-1` and the like are files contained within `x.zip`.  For the remainder of this answer, I will be assuming the current directory contains two `.zip` files: `x.zip` and `y.zip`.

When the shell performs a glob expansion (wildcards such as `*` or `?`), each matching file becomes a separate argument.  So

```
$ unzip *.zip
```

turns into

```
$ unzip x.zip y.zip
```

Remember, this syntax means "extract the file `y.zip` from the archive `x.zip`".  In order to allow multiple archives, `unzip` will also process wildcards.  If you want to let `unzip` handle the wildcards instead of the shell, you have to either quote or escape them:

```
$ unzip \*.zip
```

or

```
$ unzip '*.zip'
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments.. You brought some light and helped me dig better..!!